# Rails custom auth not registering sign_in user in controller tests

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

I created my authentication system based on Hartl's Rails Tutorial and am having issues with controller tests.

**engagements_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe EngagementsController do
  describe "GET show" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { sign_in user }

    it "assigns requested engagement to @engagement" do
      engagement = FactoryGirl.create(:engagement, user: user)
      get :show, id: engagement
      assigns[:engagement].should eq(engagement)
    end

    it "renders :show" do
      engagement = FactoryGirl.create(:engagement, user: user)
      get :show, :id => engagement.id
      expect(response).to render_template("show")
    end
  end
end
```

**Errors I'm getting:**

```
 EngagementsController GET show renders :show
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template("show")
   expecting <"show"> but rendering with <[]>
 # ./spec/controllers/engagements_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in < top (required)>'

 EngagementsController GET show assigns requested engagement to @engagement
 Failure/Error: assigns[:engagement].should eq(engagement)  
 expected: #<Engagement id: 42, title: "Coding", content: "Got in the zone with coding", user_id: 46, created_at: "2014-08-28 21:08:43", updated_at: "2014-08-28 21:08:43", photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil>
        got: nil
   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/engagements_controller_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in < top (required)>'
```

**engagements_controller.rb**

```
class EngagementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:show]

  def show
    @engagement = Engagement.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def correct_user
    @engagement = current_user.engagements.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @engagement.nil? && !current_user.try(:admin)
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

I have tried every answer I could find with no luck. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for edits, @zishe. This was my first post on SO, but I'll make sure it doesn't happen again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Before in the controller I had:

```
before { sign_in user }
```

However, in a controller spec, Capybara should be disabled. Thus, using:

```
before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }
```

made it work.

I understand why this works, but not enough to be able to explain it. If anyone has a good explanation, that'd be great! :)